# Sharing and odd pizza

Tags: contest-math, game-theory

Here is a classical problem, which every mathematician will have seen at least onece in their life:

> Anne and Ben are sharing a pizza. The pizza is divided into an even number of pieces of unequal sizes. Anne takes the first slice, and then she and Ben alternate, always taking slices adjacent to the created hole (so that the remaining part of the pizza remains connected). Can Anne always guarantee that she gets at least as much pizza as Ben?

If you haven't seen this one yet, you might want to give it a minute's thought. *Hint*: the solution is simple and elegant. It's useful to separate the pizza into "even" and "odd" pieces.

**Question:** What happens when the pizza is divided into an *odd* number of pieces?

Clearly, for $3$ pieces Alice can guarantee to eat $\geq 1/2$ of pizza (but can't in general do better). Does this remain true in general?

Comment: Is the size of each slice unique?

Comment: @Ovi: No, when I said "unequal" what I really meant was "not necessarily equal".

Comment: Are you asking because you want the answer or asking because you're conducting a contest ?

Comment: I only found this that if two non-adjacent pieces add up to 0.5 or more then Anne can do it...but I guess you have seen that long ago. Can you extend it to 3 non adjacent pieces adding up to 0.5 or more?

Comment: I haven't read it, but doesn't http://arxiv.org/pdf/0812.4322v1.pdf say "no, she can't"? Also see http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1629325/56801

Comment: @user230452 - I'm asking because I'm curious what the answer may be.

Comment: @Keepthesemind - Yes, thanks for digging it up! Problem solved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sharing a pepperoni pizza with your worst enemy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1629263/sharing-a-pepperoni-pizza-with-your-worst-enemy)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps: You give it the pizza slices and it gives you the max pizza amount that player $A$ can guarantee.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int A[100];

int maxline( vector <int> V){ //this solves the problem when the slices are in a line
    int N=V.size();
    int M[100][100]; //M[i][j] stores the max pizza amount 
                    //when we only consider slices i,i+1...i+j-1
    for(int i=1;i<=N;i++){
        for(int j=0;j+i-1<N;j++){ //here we fill the matrix recursively with linear programming
            if(i==1) M[j][i]=V[j];
            if(i==2) M[j][i]= max(V[j],V[j+1]);
            if(i>2) M[j][i]= max( V[j] + min(M[j+2][i-2],M[j+1][i-2]), V[j+i-1]+min(M[j][i-2],M[j+1][i-2]));
        }
    }
    return(M[0][N]);
}

int main(){
    int N,T=0,res=0;
    scanf("%d",&N);
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        scanf("%d",&A[i]);
        T+=A[i];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){ // this just iterates over all possible first picks.
        vector <int> V;
        for(int j=(i+1)%N;j!=i;j=(j+1)%N){
            V.push_back(A[j]);
        }
        res=max(res,T-maxline(V));
    }
    printf("%d\n",res);
}
```

Comment: So far everything I have tried gives me that $A$ can guarantee at least half of the pizza.

Comment: I trief every combination in which slice have integer size between $0$ and $10$ and in which there are at most $7$ slices, $A$ can win in all of them.

Comment: My algorithm agrees with the paper, it says $A$ can guarantee at most $4$ with slices 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1